# How to make file_get_contents() working?

Tags: linux, php

I am trying to use a basic example from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-file_get_contents-function/ e.g. the following code:

```
<?php 

 // reading contents from the 
 // geeksforgeeks homepage 
 $homepage = file_get_contents("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"); 
 echo $homepage; 

?>
```

inside my index.php page but it just doesn't work at all. I mean the browser starts "thinking" for about 30 seconds and then, without any error or smth, it stops and shows me everything that there was before - without any new information that's supposed to come from the above mentioned code...

Why is it happening? It says everywhere that "the file_get_contents() function in PHP is an inbuilt function" so as far as I understood I do not require to install something additional on my Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the http wrappers for the various file functions - including `file_get_contents()` enabled? Check your php.ini or output of `phpinfo()`

Comment: Are you running on an SELinux enabled system? If so, SELinux could block outgoing network connections. Please run your code again and do a `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i` and edit your question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if there's no error in the log, i'd check the iptables/firewall configuration for «I mean the browser starts "thinking" for about 30 seconds» seems to me standard timeout for "no answer".

Comment: 30 second delay does sound like a time out of sorts.

Comment: well default_socket_timeout is 60''...so 30'' might be